# Java bot using the Robot class

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a game bot using the Robot class.
I have tried the following code to perform a right click of the mouse:

```
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
```

And it worked.

I'm testing it on a client side 3d online game.

Pressing the key "1" should perform some kind of a movement ingame, and when I tried the following code it didn't worked:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

But it did worked when I used that code while speaking in the chat in game.

It's been tested over and over and I keep getting the same result.

Is it something that I have done wrong?or somehow the game detect that I'm not the one that pressing that key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably releasing the key too quickly. Try sleeping for 30~60ms before releasing the key:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
try {
    Thread.sleep(50);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

Comment: @ImriPersiado If it fixed your issue, you should be able to accept nneonneo's answer already, I don't believe SO restricts anyone's ability to accept answers.